# How to convert string from one charset to another in C++?

Tags: c++, character-encoding

How to convert string from one charset to another in C++ in a portable way? For example I want to convert to wstring to UTF-8 character array or . How to do this?

I am asking some standard way no chilkatsoft, wxWidgets, Qt. Its a plain C++ application. Though some simple class or methods will do the job.

Comment: Your solution is only going to be as portable as the libraries you use (ICU is *very* portable, for example).  If you insist on using no libraries at all, you should be prepared to copy lookup tables with thousands and thousands of entries.

Comment: utf-16 and utf-8 are both different encodings of the same underlying numbers, so its quite possible to do this transformation in a very small platform independent way.
For everything else, lots of character encodings only make sense or are defined on a single platform, this is one of those places where it makes sense to have a file - or files - with platform specific character set transformation routines.

Comment: Hello priyank
Regard
Anirudha Gupta
http://anirudhagupta.blogspot.com

Comment: I am anirudha you can contact me @ http://anirudhagupta.blogspot.com/2009/11/give-feedback-for-improve-this-blog.html. but don't disclosed your mail address in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Boost Serialization library contains a [UTF-8 codecvt facet](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html).

Answer (score 3):

The common repetoire for character sets is Unicode. Hence, you'd want a Unicode-oriented library. Frameworks like Qt and wxWidgets offer some of this functionality; ICU is more specific to Unicode text processing.

Comment: I am asking in standard C++, you should know the baggage of wxWidgets or Qt.

Comment: The implied prerequisite is: there is no functionality for conversions between character sets in c++.

Comment: Indeed. And the reason that there is "baggage" in those libraries is because there's so much possible with computers, most of which isn't standardized by ISO. One mans bagage is another mans essential function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use libiconv (Google it ), it supports many encodings.

Comment: how portable libiconv is? and is there any samples?